# JMeter - Is there a need to explicitly call embedded resources?

Tags: jmeter

We are using JMeter's built-in HTTP Proxy to record a test case. It was decided to capture all requests going to the server, and therefore there is no include/exclude rule set in the proxy. My question is whether there is a necessity in load testing to capture calls to JS, CSS, PNGs and other embedded resources?

So, technically speaking if I call a JSP that includes such resources, JSs, CSSs and images then will their timings (such as response time and latency) be automatically included in JMeter? I know that JMeter is not a browser and therefore it cannot execute client-side scripts but does it automatically discover/consider such resources even when there is not any explicit call to them in the test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question,

YES you can remove all embedded resources from being explicitly called.  Requests have a checkbox on the bottom that says "retrieve embedded resources".  This would grab all CSS, JPG, etc.

It's also a great way to find broken links and resources in a web app.

Comment: OK! Then, I remove all such resources from the test case and instead tick that checkbox. That would should result in a much cleaner test case!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does record all those resources you mentioned. If you look at the recorded test you'll see all you CSS, PNG, js etc files listed too. You can simply remove them if you think some or all are not relevant to your test.

Comment: Yes, I do know exactly what you mean. But, part of my question is whether we can remove the recorded calls to all those listed files (png, css, js, etc.). I mean does JMeter automatically extract such resources from the page (e.g. a JSP page) when I call the target page and execute them automatically without having the need to have them explicitly listed in the test case. This would result in a much cleaner test case!